# .NET Identity Role/Claim structuring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

**Background**
I'm building an application that I want to use ASP.NET identity to manage my authorization to a web api module that I will be deploying to azure (1 project is an azure web app the other is an azure api service).

I'm a bit confused as to how I should leverage roles and claims to work together with how to structure the application or if there is another built in feature in the identity system that would work better for my solution.

My front end is built using Angular and my APIs are in C# (.net 4.6)

**My project is:** 
Each user belongs to one or more group(s).  Each user has different permissions in each group.  Users can switch between groups (or see aggregate data across all groups they belong to) after they have logged in (i.e. 1 jwt token per login and that token needs to define what groups and what permissions per group the user has).

**Question:**
I'm not entirely sure how Asp.net identity best practice is to structure this.  Should I create a role for each group that exists in the system (potentially thousands) and then give a claim for each permission that a user has within that group (role)?

Comment: Could you give an example of a group and a permission for the group in your scenario?

Comment: For example, a group is a team and you are hired by multiple teams to perform certain tasks within that team.  Your two groups are the 49ers and Seahawks.  When you are in the 49ers context (selected the 49ers as your group), you can manage the roster (add/edit/delete i.e. the permissions you are granted within that group).  In the Seahawks context, you can manage game lineups (add/edit/delete) for the game but you cant manage the roster.  In this scenario could your Roles be 49ers and Seahawks, while the actual permissions in that group are the claims?  Or am I thinking about this wrong.

Comment: No, you are not, however, the level of granularity you decide this becomes claims or rather you evaluate this based on the data upon each request is up to you. We had like 3000 roles in one of thr deployment, it was 200 units (your groups) times 15 permissions where actual groups were like `Seahawks_management` and this was ok.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorZychla.  I'm going to go ahead with your suggestion.